# Cant login to aws ec2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The instance is running ubuntu 18 in my public_html folder, there is a folder called users I wanted to change all the subfolder permissions to 777 to I did the following command inside the public_html folder

```
find users -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

and now I cannot log in to the instance it says

```
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Comment: You should never chmod 777 anything, not even for "testing". You should ignore anyone who recommends it. It is highly destructive. It is possible that you will have to build a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH keys need to have specific permissions otherwise they won't work. Easiest is to restore from backup, which in AWS is a snapshot.

If you don't have a backup then you can:

1. Stop your instance
2. Mount the volume to another instance
3. Change the permissions back ([permissionshere](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder))
4. Mount the volume back to an instance as the main volume.